# Scripted Import to Container

Tags: import, containers, filemaker

I have a spreadsheet that is exported via a scheduled script, that exports the spreadsheet to the Documents path, I wanted to know is it possible to export said spreadsheet to be stored into a container field in FileMaker?

So basically the script will run, and dump the exported file into a container field rather than the docs file.

I have been trying for a good while to achieve this but I cant for the life of me get it to work, is it impossible? Or am I just dumb!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the file to the Documents or temporary folder, and then import it with the Insert From URL script step.

Comment: Thankyou for the response, Andreas! Can you please explain a little more in depth? As I'm struggling to make this work.

Comment: So annoying what Insert File does not work on the server. Sean, you need to show what you have done so far to get help.

Comment: Something like this should work: Insert from URL [ Table::Containerfield ; "file://" & Get(Documentspath) & "spreadsheet.xlsx"] . You can set the filepath in a variable first if you prefer that.

Comment: Thankyou, Andreas that has cracked it for me. Thanks also Nicolai